# Markov Inequality for almost positive random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I came across the following problem in my research, where I want to apply Markov inequality to bound the tail probability of a random variable, X.

However, the random variable X is not strictly positive. But I have the following additional information
$P(X < 0) < \epsilon$, for small $\epsilon$.

Can I still apply Markov inequality? Are there any additional conditions required ?

Comment: So you have P(X<0)=0. Assume that P(X<0)>0. The n There is a positive $\epsilon$ so that P(X<0)>$\epsilon$. Contradiction!!!

Comment: @zoli I am not sure what you meant by P(X<0)=0. I never claimed that.

Comment: @user65998, although you never claimed that $P(X<0)=0$, it is nevertheless implied by the information that $P(X<0)<\epsilon$ for arbitrary small $\epsilon$. Is that not what you meant?

Comment: @user65998 I think there was a mistake in the question  . I meant $P(X < 0) < \epsilon$, for small $\epsilon$. Edited the question.

Comment: Oh! For _some_ small epsilon. I misanderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any additional assumption we cannot expect that a Markov inequality holds:

---

Define a random variable on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1]))$ (endowed with Lebesgue measure) by

$$X(\omega) = \begin{cases} n, & \omega \in \left[ \frac{1}{n}, 1 \right], \\ -n (n-1), & \omega \in \big[0, \frac{1}{n} \big). \end{cases}$$

This random variable satisfies $\mathbb{E}X=0$ and $\mathbb{P}(X<0) = \frac{1}{n}$ is "small". On the other hand, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(X>a) = 1- \frac{1}{n}$$

for any $a \in (0,n)$. Consequently, since $\mathbb{E}X=0$, we cannot expect that

$$\mathbb{P}(X>a) \leq \frac{1}{a} \mathbb{E}X.$$

---

This shows that we do not only need information on the probability $\mathbb{P}(X<0)$, but a (nice) bound on $|X(\omega)|$, $\omega \in \{X<0\}$. Roughly speaking, we have to ensure that

$$\mathbb{E}(X 1_{\{X<0\}})$$

is small compared to

$$\mathbb{E}(X 1_{\{X>0\}}).$$

Comment: Thanks. The variable X is the maximum of a bunch of dependent Gaussian random variables. Is there any simpler condition that I can prove in this case ?

Comment: @user65998 None that I'm aware of.